# GAE+Django server getting called twice for every request

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am running a GAE server with django (locally on my dev machine). The view corresponding to every requests is getting called twice. any idea on how to orrect this.

I am using firefox 3.6.8 on ubuntu 9.10 for this.

the following is the debug output ->

http://pastebin.com/4CetCK5J

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the last line:

```
INFO     2010-08-05 04:18:17,518 dev_appserver.py:3268] "GET /register/static/images/site-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It looks to me like you've got a broken URI in your HTML, which is causing your browser to try and fetch an image from the wrong URL, loading your (perhaps overly permissive) handler instead.

Comment: Thsi is not a broken url. its actually a relative url ( relativce to the site-domain).

Comment: But your URL isn't relative to the root - you omitted the leading '/'. As a result, it's trying to fetch a static image - site-icon.png - from your dynamic handler, which is causing the duplicate request.